Movie in which a person claims to be Jesus
I heard this story about the movie from my friends few years ago. There is no exact plotting I can remember, only thing I remeber is that entire/most of movie is slow and there are conversations talking about various things between a few people and once the topic comes to spirituality or god and in the arguments, one guy claims himself to be Jesus and happens to prove he is in fact Jesus who is roaming the world (by staying at the same location not more than 10 years).

Sounds like The Man From Earth from 2007. From IMDb:

An impromptu goodbye party for Professor John Oldman becomes a mysterious interrogation after the retiring scholar reveals to his colleagues he never ages and has walked the earth for 14,000 years. 

John claims that he is Jesus, among other people. He moves around every 10 years to avoid suspicion. The entire movie depicts John's conversation with his colleagues, and one of them is startled to discover

that John is actually his father; the revelation causes him to have a heart attack and die.

Here's the trailer:



